# Getting Invalid Syntax error for elif statement. how to overcome this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm trying to run this code but getting the error and spent all my time debugging.looking out for help

```
n = int(input())
if n % 2 == 1: 
 print("Weird")
elif(n%2==0) and 2<=n<=5:      
     print("Not Weird")
elif(n%2==0) and 6<=n<=20:
         print("Weird")
else:
             print(" Not Weird")
```

Comment: Please add the code.

Comment: sorry took time due to indentation

Comment: The indentation shown here is not correct

Answer (score 3):

The `if/elif/else` statements must all be at the same indentation level.

```
if x:
    # do stuff
elif y:
    # do other stuff
elif z:
    # do more stuff
else:
    # do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not indent elif and else.  They should be at same indent as if.  Also, you don't need to encase your conditional statements in parenthesis. This works:

```
n = int(input())
if n%2 == 1:
 print("Weird")
elif n%2 == 0:      
    print("Not Weird")
elif n%2 == 0 and 6 <= n <= 20:
    print("Weird")
else:
    print(" Not Weird")
```